# How to change the color of the title of the label "crossref-def-title" in Quarto?

Tags: html, quarto

I would like to change the color of the label "Definition" using

```
:::{#def-definition1 style="color:red"}
example
:::
```

change the color of the block, not just the title

```
:::{#def-definition1 style="color:red"}
example
:::
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your output format is html, you can use CSS to change the color for the `.definition` class.

```
---
title: Untitled
format: html
crossref: 
  def-title: Defn
css: style.css
---

:::{#def-definition1}
example
:::
```

**style.css**

```
.definition .theorem-title strong {
  color: red;
}
```

---

[image: rendered output]